# Print a file using AJAX JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I wanted to use AJAX to read a JSON file, then print its elements for example all the names.
For the moment I wrote this:

File JSON:

```
[{
    "JarvanIV": {
        "id": 59,
        "title": "the Exemplar of Demacia",
        "stats": {
            "attackrange": 175,
            "mpperlevel": 40,
            "mp": 302.2,
            "attackdamage": 55.712,
            "hp": 571.2,
            "hpperlevel": 90,
            "attackdamageperlevel": 3.4,
            "armor": 29,
            "mpregenperlevel": 0.45,
            "hpregen": 8.175,
            "critperlevel": 0,
            "spellblockperlevel": 1.25,
            "mpregen": 6.755,
            "attackspeedperlevel": 2.5,
            "spellblock": 32.1,
            "movespeed": 340,
            "attackspeedoffset": -0.05,
            "crit": 0,
            "hpregenperlevel": 0.7,
            "armorperlevel": 3.6
        },
        "name": "Jarvan IV",
        "key": "JarvanIV"
    },
    "Ezreal": {
        "id": 81,
        "title": "the Prodigal Explorer",
        "stats": {
            "attackrange": 550,
            "mpperlevel": 42,
            "mp": 360.6,
            "attackdamage": 55.66,
            "hp": 484.4,
            "hpperlevel": 80,
            "attackdamageperlevel": 2.41,
            "armor": 21.88,
            "mpregenperlevel": 0.65,
            "hpregen": 6.42,
            "critperlevel": 0,
            "spellblockperlevel": 0,
            "mpregen": 8.09,
            "attackspeedperlevel": 2.8,
            "spellblock": 30,
            "movespeed": 325,
            "attackspeedoffset": 0,
            "crit": 0,
            "hpregenperlevel": 0.55,
            "armorperlevel": 3.5
        },
        "name": "Ezreal",
        "key": "Ezreal"
    }
}]
```

HTML file with AJAX function:

```
<body>
    <div id="champion"></div>
    <script>
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open('GET', 'champStat.json');
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if ((request.readyState === 4) && (request.status === 200)) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                var output;
                for (var index in obj) {
                    output += "" + obj[index].name;
                }
                var doc = document.getElementById("champion");
                doc.innerHTML = output;
            }
        }
        request.send();
    </script>
</body>
```

But I can't print the name,  it is the first time I use a JSON file so I would not have made mistakes in writing, or I was wrong in the AJAX function.

Comment: change the `for` loop as `var output='';
        for (var index in obj[0]) {
            output += " " + obj[0][index].name;
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON has a weird structure, as the nested object has a key that redundantly carries the name (and key) you have in the next structure.

But apart from that, this will work (I left out the AJAX part as this is probably not your problem, and put the parsed object in `json`):

```
    var output;
    for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
        obj = json[i];
        for (var char in obj) {
          output += obj[char].name;
          console.log(obj[char].name);
        }
    }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r3kuet7z/)

If you modify your JSON structure a bit, you can do it a lot easier:

```
var json = [
       {
         "id": 59,
         "title": "the Exemplar of Demacia",
         "stats": {
            "attackrange": 175,
            "mpperlevel": 40,
            "mp": 302.2,
            "attackdamage": 55.712,
            "hp": 571.2,
            "hpperlevel": 90,
            "attackdamageperlevel": 3.4,
            "armor": 29,
            "mpregenperlevel": 0.45,
            "hpregen": 8.175,
            "critperlevel": 0,
            "spellblockperlevel": 1.25,
            "mpregen": 6.755,
            "attackspeedperlevel": 2.5,
            "spellblock": 32.1,
            "movespeed": 340,
            "attackspeedoffset": -0.05,
            "crit": 0,
            "hpregenperlevel": 0.7,
            "armorperlevel": 3.6
         },
         "name": "Jarvan IV",
         "key": "JarvanIV"
      },
      {
         "id": 81,
         "title": "the Prodigal Explorer",
         "stats": {
            "attackrange": 550,
            "mpperlevel": 42,
            "mp": 360.6,
            "attackdamage": 55.66,
            "hp": 484.4,
            "hpperlevel": 80,
            "attackdamageperlevel": 2.41,
            "armor": 21.88,
            "mpregenperlevel": 0.65,
            "hpregen": 6.42,
            "critperlevel": 0,
            "spellblockperlevel": 0,
            "mpregen": 8.09,
            "attackspeedperlevel": 2.8,
            "spellblock": 30,
            "movespeed": 325,
            "attackspeedoffset": 0,
            "crit": 0,
            "hpregenperlevel": 0.55,
            "armorperlevel": 3.5
         },
         "name": "Ezreal",
         "key": "Ezreal"
      }
];

  var output;
  for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
    obj = json[i];
    output += obj.name;
    console.log(obj.name);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the way you want to access the name is different.

Hope this snippet will work

```
 // need to get the first object
    var getObj = obj[0];
   // it will return the keys example ezreal,jaravan
    var getKeys = Object.keys(getObj);
    // now loop over getObj, and access each object and retrieve the name
    getKeys.forEach(function(item){
      console.log(getObj[item].name);

    })
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/pbszus12/1/)